# Laravel: Artisan command error while using request inside config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I used `request()` inside config file of my installed package [laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) under my `url_prefix` I need to set target depends on my url so I used a `request()->segment(2)` everything works file except can't use of artisan command I got an error showing of

> [ReflectionException] 
>   Class request does not exist

Using of `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` does not work as well

lfm.php

```
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Include to pre-defined routes from package or not. Middlewares
    'use_package_routes' => true,

    // Middlewares which should be applied to all package routes.
    // For laravel 5.1 and before, remove 'web' from the array.
    'middlewares' => ['web'],

    // The url to this package. Change it if necessary.
    'url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager/'.request()->segment(2),
```

So in able to use artisan command what I'm doing is to remove the `request()->segment(2)` for the moment and bring it back after done using it very hassle. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You can't use request object in your config files - they're loaded when application is bootstrapped and request object is not set up yet.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Thanks is there an alternative way?

Comment: Set the prefix on a service provider

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Have two questions about add 
 first: does config/session run on EVERY request? and set this  'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),

second: is there a way in here to set this to true or false based on the URL

Answer (score 0):

Since the Request class is only available for Http requests, you shouldn't use it in config file and so.
Lets initiate url_prefix in your **AppServicePrivider.php** boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    config(['app.url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager/'.request()->segment(2)]);
}
```